# Long format separation issue

Tags: r

From this dataframe:

```
dftest <-  data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("java-ee?jsf?omnifaces?jpa"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to produce a dataframe like this

```
data.frame(id = c(1), java-ee = c(1), jsf = c(1), onifaces = c(1), jpa = c(1))
```

I use this commands to make it:

```
s2 <- strsplit(dftest$text, split = "?")
dftest2 <- data.frame(id = rep(dftest2$id, sapply(s2, length)), text = unlist(s2))

dflike_final <- reshape(dftest2, idvar = "id", timevar = "text", direction = "wide")
```

Howver the results from the first two line is this:

> ```
>  id text
> 1   1         j
> 2   1         a
> 3   1         v
> 4   1         a
> 5   1         -
> 6   1         e
> 7   1         e
> 8   1         ?
> 9   1         j
> 10  1         s
> 11  1         f
> 12  1         ?
> 13  1         o
> 14  1         m
> 15  1         n
> 16  1         i
> 17  1         f
> 18  1         a
> 19  1         c
> 20  1         e
> 21  1         s
> 22  1         ?
> 23  1         j
> 24  1         p
> 25  1         a
> ```

How can I fix it to have the whole string?

Comment: `?` is a special symbol in regular expressions. You need to escape it or use `strsplit(dftest$text, split = "?", fixed = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can bring the `text` in separate rows, create a dummy column (`n`) and get the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dftest %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = "\\?") %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = n, names_from = text)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
#     id `java-ee`   jsf omnifaces   jpa
#  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1         1     1         1     1
```

---

As mentioned by @Roland `?` is a special character in regex we need to escape it. Also you need to include a dummy column in creating the new dataframe. You can then use your attempt as

```
s2 <- strsplit(dftest$text, split = "\\?")
dftest2 <- data.frame(id = rep(dftest$id, lengths(s2)), text = unlist(s2), n = 1)
dflike_final <- reshape(dftest2, idvar = "id", timevar = "text", direction = "wide")
```